# Как запустить php скрипт через ssh соединение?

Tags: php, bash, ssh, sh

У меня есть доступ к хостингу по ssh. Я хочу работать через консоль с командами фрэймворка Laravel `artisan`. Но я не могу запустить скрипт php через ssh соединение. В консоли пишу так:

```
php artisan ...
```

Пробовал еще так:

```
#/usr/bin/php artisan ...
```

, хотя не понимаю, что это значит, (это попытка запустить консоль bash через ssh?):

В ответ получаю, что такая команда не найдена. Это ограничения моего хостинга, или я что-то делаю не так?

**UPD:**
1. ищу php на сервере командой `whereis php`
2. получаю ответ `php: /usr/lib/php`
3. ввожу команду `/usr/lib/php -v`
4. получаю ответ: `-sh: /usr/lib/php: is a directory`
5. Что это значит? Что я в этом случае делаю не так?

**UPD2 Ответ** Оказалось на шаред хостинге установлено несколько версий Php, из за чего доступ к каждой из них имеет свой путь. Этот путь не увидишь при помощи команды `whereis php` По вопросу в поддержке - мне предоставили эту информацию.

Comment: Уточнил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не беда, когда человек спрашивает про то, чего не понимает. Мы все учились.  Беда, когда тот же самый человек начинает пытаться учить других и отвечать на любой вопрос, который видит на сайте.

"через ssh" никакую консоль запускать не надо. SSH - это УЖЕ консоль. После соединения с сервером мы УЖЕ на сервере и про SSH можно забыть. поэтому вопрос должен звучать просто "как запустить РНР скрипт через командную строку". И ответ на него простой:

Во-первых, надо указывать правильный путь к РНР интерпретатору. Если, паче чаяния, РНР не находится в PATH и нельзя написать просто `php`, то можно набрать команду `whereis php` и посмотреть полный путь к интерпретатору.

В-вторых, надо указывать правильный путь к РНР-файлу. Для чего либо сначала перейти в папку, где файл лежит, либо указать полный путь, `php /path/to/file`

И, разумеется, **надо обязательно читать сообщения об ошибках**, поскольку в них говорится, что именно мы делаем неправильно и что надо исправить.

Если whereis не выводит путь к бинарнику РНР, то это значит, что версия для командной строки не установлена. Надо почитать в гугле, как установить php-cli для своей операционной системы.

Comment: Даже не знаю, что мне, оправдываться теперь, что я пытаюсь отвечать на вопросы? Не знаю пути лучше для обучения, чем попытаться объяснить что-то другому. Я часто ошибаюсь, но на этих ошибках я учусь. За ответ спасибо.

Comment: Stack Overflow - не сайт для обучения. Это сайт для ответов на вопросы.

Comment: А для чего ответы на вопросы - если не для обучения?

Comment: Ладно, я пишу whereis php. Вижу адрес `/usr/lib/php` Ввожу команду `/usr/lib/php -v` - мне выдает ответ `-sh: /usr/lib/php: is a directory` Что это значит?

Comment: переводится как "это директория", посмотрите что там внутри

Comment: @Ипатьев, к тому же отвечаю только на те вопросы, в ответах на которые я уверен. Если и ошибаюсь - это были мои заблуждения. Они у всех есть. И у вас, в том числе - уверен. Так что это просто рабочий процесс - не более.

Comment: OlegUP, там папка `modules`, в ней находится один файл `phpcups.so`, и я знаю, как это переводится, просто у себя на локальной машине, выполняя то же самое, мне удается запустить php скрипт, а на хостинге - нет.

Comment: там, кроме папки modules, наверное, есть еще фалы, которые я не вижу, потому что в ответе так же выдает строку total 8

Comment: думаю у вас, как у новичка debian -based дистрибутив поэтому выполните   dpkg -l | grep php

Comment: а просто `php -v` у вас ничего не выдает ?

Comment: Пробуйте еще так , через окружение `/usr/bin/env php -v` так кстати и сам artisan ищет php .

Comment: @OlegUp, команда dpkg так же не найдена.

Comment: @redroid, эта команда так же выдает ошибку, что команда не найдена. Через окружение так же ничего не находит. Нет искомых файлов или директорий.

Comment: @Razzwan какая ОС на хостинге?

Comment: @OlegUP, linux-gnu

Comment: @Razzwan Какой дистрибутив имею ввиду?

Comment: @OlegUP, я не знаю, как посмотреть.

Comment: @Razzwan Учитесь гуглить и читайте ошибки, выполните uname -a

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31039/discussion-between-razzwan-and-olegup).

Answer (score 1):

Artisan - php файл который находится обычно в  корне проекта на laravel [image: ssh]

Перейдите в папку вашего проекта и сделай то что уже делал `php artisan` , или укажи путь к ней полный 
обычно это как то так `php /var/www/www-user/data/www/laravel/artisan` .
В общем ты все правильно делал и если бы на `artisan` был прокинут симилинк в `/usr/bin/artisan` , то все бы сработало .

Comment: Да, что такое artisan, я знаю. Это просто php файл. И с маршрутами тоже понятно. Но это по-прежнему не работает. За участие благодарен.